# how can i make the View do NOT expand over its sibling View

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout similiar to this:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
     <EditText android:id="@+id/editbox" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" .../>
     <Button android:layout_right="@id/editbox" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

The button is at the right of the edit text. And the edit text is 'wrap_content'. When i type texts into the edit view, the view's width increase and will expand to my button. I want the two views (button and edit text) have their own area. How to configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Keyin Lynx: Use minWidth and maxWidth attribute,For Instance:

android:minWidth="10dip", android:maxWidth="60dip", attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  `android:layout_right="@id/editbox` use this `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` so that the Button will be always placed at right side of the EditText

Comment: Yes, the button is always at the right side. But my question is, the edit text will become bigger when i type texts into it. And the button will on the top of the edit text. That's wired.

Comment: yup then you can set width of EditText dynamically by substracting the width of Button from the width of your RelativeLayout and set it to the width of EditText.